# Fitting big table of data into iPhone

Tags: tables, ios, iphone, reports

Im designing iPhone 4 app, and one of the requirements is to place a big report there.

So in Excel it looks like this:

[image: table]

It has about 100 rows. I need to implement a filter by "Item Name" as well.

Does anyone have experience about how to design this report best? So its user-friendly and usable?

Comment: A wide table is not the only way to present your data. You may want to make thick rows with data lines one under another. Please also read Edward Tufte's books (such as this one - ISBN 0961392142).

Comment: We need to know more about the use cases of this table to come up with an optimal design.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should **look for solution in more general level, not in layout level**. Such a big table is hard perceived even on desktop screen, not saying of mobile devices.

Probably the table itself is not the thing user wants. It is the mean of data organization for further processing. So think more generally: what is the user task? Is all the data necessary for decision making? Are some things could be done automatically to reduce user load?

Posting more specific information on your task will help to find solution.

And even if your task is to flood user with numbers, do it gently:
[image: improved table]

- **Make the rows easy to read** – zebra-colored table background
- **Display only actual data on default** – `Param 3` folded to only 2013 data
- **Make changes noticable** – compared to previous period
- **Display data on demand** – look at unfolded 2012 data for `Param 3`

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is probably not "to place a big report", but to provide the user with some information. At least, that's what it *should be* :). Currently that information may be presented in this report, but that doesn't make it the only way. You need to understand what the users get from the report and how they get it. What are the main criteria they're using to focus on a specific row or column? Can they be used as filters on the preceding screens, to slice this data some more? In a large table users are often most interested in the outliers - the extreme values. So maybe "Top/Bottom 10" could be a good way of presenting the most interesting data here. Or they may be interested in the data chronologically. Filtering by date / meaningful time periods is another way.

Try to get your hands on a large bank's iPhone app. The current account can also be seen as a large table, but they usually manage to break it down into manageable chunks and present it in a clear and friendly way. That may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

> iPhone 4 app, and one of the requirements is to place a big report

This isn't necessarily a UX problem. This is a software development problem--namely the use of arbitrary requirements that aren't meshed with actual use cases.

I'd step back and ask the stakeholders how they envision a user digesting this data on a mobile device.

But, to answer your question, as I do realize that even though a lot of the time the problems we fixed need to be fixed outside of UX, we're often the ones left with the ball in our court and we gotta do what we gotta do.

As such, I'd strip the table down. Have one set of key data, with each row then going to a more detailed view. Yes it means the interaction will be much more of a hub-and-spoke model, but that's sometimes the reality of dealing with tiny screens.